# Manually repeating animateCss fails in Vue-cli

Tags: javascript, vue.js, animate.css, vue-cli

I want to let a  element to do "fadeInDown" and "fadeOut" animations

I click a button and use v-show to determine whether let it show up

The issue is that this animation work well at first time,

but at the second time the element will fadeInDown for a while and then **automatically** disappear(probably fadeOut)

here is my html:

```
<v-btn @click="toggler"><i class="material-icons">dehaze</i></v-btn>

<v-layout 
    :class="wallpaperClass"
    v-show="toggled" 
    id="wallpaper" 
    align-center justify-center row fill-height>
    <router-link tag="v-btn" class="blue" to="/">somewhere</router-link> 
    <router-link tag="v-btn" class="blue" to="/">somewhere</router-link> 
    <router-link tag="v-btn" class="blue" to="/">somewhere</router-link> 
    <router-link tag="v-btn" class="blue" to="/">somewhere</router-link> 
    <v-btn @click="toggler"><i class="material-icons">close</i  ></v-btn>
  </v-layout>
```

here is my script:

```
 data: () =>({
   toggled : false,
   wallpaperClass: 'animated fadeInDown'
 }),
  methods: {
    toggler() {
      var animationEnd = (function(el) {
        var animations = {
          animation: 'animationend',
          OAnimation: 'oAnimationEnd',
          MozAnimation: 'mozAnimationEnd',
          WebkitAnimation: 'webkitAnimationEnd',
        };

      for (var t in animations) {
        if (el.style[t] !== undefined) {
          return animations[t];
        }
      }
    })(document.createElement('div'));

  if(this.toggled == true) {
    this.wallpaperClass = 'animated fadeOut'
    document.getElementById("wallpaper").addEventListener(animationEnd,()=>{
      this.toggled = false
    });
  } else {
    this.toggled = true
    document.getElementById("wallpaper").addEventListener(animationEnd,()=>{
      this.wallpaperClass = 'animated fadeInDown'
    });
  }
}
}
```

I wonder if I got wrong in the toggler method, please help me this out

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is a bit messy, but I believe the `addEventListener` calls are within the `toggler` function. This is a problem, because you are adding event handlers every time you click. If you would log the functions you are adding, you will notice that you are calling multiple functions on animation end.

What you need to do is have a single animationend event handler. The nicest way to do that is to bind to the (possibly native) event in the template, but you might need to add a debounce so your function is only executed once, even if a browser defines multiple of the events.

If you cannot do that, you need to do a manual add and delete. You add a single event handler in the `mounted` lifecycle hook, and remove the same handler in the `beforeDestroy` lifecycle hook. If you do not do that, you may be introducing a memory leak. This handler will then execute code based on your `toggled` variable.

---

Further optimisations include setting the animation class based on the toggled class. In other words, you will create a computed property `wallpaperClass` that is either `'animated fadeOut'` or `'animated fadeInDown'` based on the value of `this.toggled`. You then only have to change the `toggled` variable to have your animations work automatically.

---

On a sidenote, never use `this.toggled == true`. If you expect it to be a boolean, use `this.toggled`. After all, if it is true, then it is true. You don't need to compare to anything. If it can be a truthy value and you only want to match true, use `===` to prevent it from matching converted values. If you want to convert a truthy or falsy value to an actual true or false value, you can simply do `!!variable`.

Comment: Using computed property totally solves this issue, and thanks for reminding me of the boolean, thanks!